# How can we use timer control in VB.Net Console Application?

Tags: vb.net, console

I am trying to use a Timer control in my console application.

```
Friend WithEvents XTIMER As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
```

I am setting all its properties. I have set the interval to 15000 ms. But even when I set the Enabled state of the timer control to be true, the tick event is not firing. Can any one help me out please?

Comment: Showing some code would help us diagnose the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

Comment: @@ To ALL,All these works fine in Desktop application but it is not working in onsole Application.The tick event is not firing

Comment: Thanks...This articled helped me.Appreciate your help

Answer (score 13):

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        aTimer.AutoReset = True
        aTimer.Interval = 2000 '2 seconds
        AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf tick
        aTimer.Start()
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Dim aTimer As New System.Timers.Timer

    Private Sub tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("tick")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: wow thanks. Love that Console.ReadKey() way of keeping the app alive.

Comment: I personally prefer to use `Threading.Thread.Sleep(Threading.Timeout.Infinite)` to keep the app open because it doesn't force the use of a command window.

Comment: VB.NET allows you to define the timer with `Dim WithEvents aTimer As New System.Timers.Timer`, and add `Handles aTimer.Tick` at the end of the `Sub tick` definition. You then don't need to explicitly `AddHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Timers.Timer instead. Here's a very good [comparison of the timer classes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Comment: There is also the [WPF DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Import the `System.Windows.Forms` reference and use the `Timer` class.

Comment: @downvoter: care to comment? This is a perfectly legit option. The fact that you import the System.Windows.Forms reference doesn't make it a WinForms app. If, for example, you wanted to use the Point class, would you roll out your own implementation (as a purist) or use an existing one in System.Drawing?