# Timer in vb.net Console Application

Tags: vb.net, timer, console

I looking for an example of Timer which can run my procedure or function every x minutes.
I found only examples of Windows Form project but not in a console application.

Comment: You didn't do much research, did you? (which by the way is the number one reason people down vote)  This will probably help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167365/All-about-NET-Timers-A-Comparison

Comment: If you want to run the console application every x minutes, can you not create a task in windows task scheduler? Or do you want a specific function within the console app to run?

Comment: Hi @rory.ap your link not refers to vb.net console application language. I found many Windows Forms examples but not in console application.

Comment: @tigerdi I want to have internal timer in my application to run procedures, for example one procedure which will be run once a day at specific time, and another every 5 minuts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is an answer from [How can we use timer control in VB.Net Console Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820165/how-can-we-use-timer-control-in-vb-net-console-application)

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    aTimer.AutoReset = True
    aTimer.Interval = 2000 '2 seconds
    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf tick
    aTimer.Start()
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Dim aTimer As New System.Timers.Timer

Private Sub tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("tick")
End Sub

End Module
```